# SSL exception when sending http request from blazor project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, ssl, blazor

I've a visual studio solution composed by a blazor server project, and an asp.net web api core project.

I want to send a http request from the server to the web api process, but I have an error.

This is the blazor login page:

```
@page "/access/login"
@using System.Text.Json;
@using Identity.Shared;

@inject IHttpClientFactory httpClientfactory
@inject IConfiguration configuration;
@inject ILogger<Login> logger

<form id="logincontainer">
  <div id="header">
    <h2>WCondominio - Login</h2>
    <img id="logo" src="images/256/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" @bind="_loginModel.Email" required><br>

  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" @bind="_loginModel.Password" required><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" @bind="_loginModel.RememberMe" name="rememberme">
  <label for="rememberme">Remember me</label><br>

  <input type="submit" @onclick="OnLoginClick" value="Login">
  <a href="/forgotpassword">Forgot password?</a> or <a href="/registration">Register</a>
</form>

@code {
  private LoginViewModel _loginModel { get; set; } = new LoginViewModel();

  private async void OnLoginClick()
  {
    try
    {
      logger.LogInformation("Login selected for user " + _loginModel.Email);
      var client = httpClientfactory.CreateClient();
      var request = createRequest();
      var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(request.RequestUri, _loginModel);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      if (e.InnerException != null)
      {
        logger.LogError("Exception when sending login request: " + e.Message + ". Inner exception: " + e.InnerException.Message);
      }
      else
      {
        logger.LogError("Exception when sending login request: " + e.Message);
      }
    }

  }

  HttpRequestMessage createRequest()
  {
    var hostname = configuration["Services:FrontendGateway:Host"];
    var url = hostname + "/" + configuration["Services:FrontendGateway:EndPoint:Login"];
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
    request.Content = JsonContent.Create(JsonSerializer.Serialize(_loginModel));
    return request;
  }

}
```

When I send the request, I obtain an `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException`:

> "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors".

Both projects are configured for using ssl.

In order to run everything I'm using the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

# Project services

  myproject.frontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myprojectfrontend
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Servers/MyProject.Frontend/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - frontendnetwork

  frontend.gateway.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}frontendgatewayapi
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Services/Frontend.Gateway.API/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - frontendnetwork
      - backendnetwork


# External services
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGDATA=/data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

networks:
  frontendnetwork:
    external: true
  backendnetwork:
    external: true

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
  pgadmin-data:
    driver: local
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I send successfully the request to the gateway service?